# find the exact or next closest date group a specific date falls into

Tags: javascript

so my json data looks like this:

```
 [ {"begin": "2018-01-01", "end": "2018-01-07", "id":"a"}, {"begin":"2018-01-08", "end":"2018-01-15", "id":"b"}, {"begin":"2018-03-01", "end":"2018-03-07", "id":"y"}]
```

it goes like this at a gap of 7 days/ a week. Given a specific date, I want to pick up its id based on the dates to falls to. E.g. 2018-01-01 to 2018-01-07 would be id a etc.

But sometimes a week might not exist e.g. all February weeks are missing. So in that case, if I want id of say 2018-02-25, I should get the next closest group, which is id y.

Currently, I am getting for dates that fall in an exact group but not if they are missing or not found, as shown below. Ideally, I would love to loop the json data only once but am open to an efficient solution.

```
const date = new Date(); //get todays date but care about month and day only
let client_date = new Date(2018, date.getMonth()  , date.getDate());

let data = parsed_data.filter(value => {

    const start_date_parts = value['begin'].split('-');
    const end_date_parts  = value['end'].split('-');

    const start_date = new Date(start_date_parts[0], start_date_parts[1]-1, start_date_parts[2]);
    const end_date = new Date(end_date_parts[0], end_date_parts[1]-1, end_date_parts[2]);

    // compare now client_date

    if (client_date >= start_date && client_date <= end_date){
        return value;
    }


});
```

it works as expected for dates that have a group representation in the json data but not for others. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should calculate the difference between the passed datetimes adding `.getTime()` to get a timestamp value.

```js
let parsed_data =  [
  {"begin": "2018-01-01", "end": "2018-01-07", "id":"a"}, 
  {"begin":"2018-01-08", "end":"2018-01-15", "id":"b"}, 
  {"begin":"2018-03-01", "end":"2018-03-07", "id":"y"}
];

const date = new Date(); //get todays date but care about month and day only
let client_date = new Date(2018, date.getMonth()  , date.getDate()).getTime();

// Set default
let i = parsed_data[0];

// Set diff to timediff in 10 years
let diff = 60*60*24*365*10000;

// Loop the data
parsed_data.forEach(function(value, index) {
    let start_date_parts = value['begin'].split('-');
    let end_date_parts  = value['end'].split('-');

    let start_date = new Date(start_date_parts[0], start_date_parts[1]-1, start_date_parts[2]).getTime();
    let end_date = new Date(end_date_parts[0], end_date_parts[1]-1, end_date_parts[2]).getTime();
      
    if (Math.abs(start_date - client_date) < diff) {
      diff = Math.abs(start_date - client_date); // set new diff value
      i = parsed_data[index];
    }
  
    if (Math.abs(end_date - client_date) < diff) {
      diff = Math.abs(start_date - client_date); // set new diff value
      i = parsed_data[index];
    }
});

console.log(i); // the closest datetime
console.log('The id: ' + i['id']) // the id you need
```

Comment: Hi...why did you do 10 years? It works as expected but i am missing the 10 years diff at the start.

Comment: @samsam I just needed a large number to compare the diff value against :-) It could be any large number, but I thought 10 years should be save.

Answer (score 0):

As you scan the array, remember which group is the closest to the target date of all seen so far.  That way, if you exhaust the search and don't find a match, you'll know which was the closest.

Comment: thanks Scott...i had the idea but putting into code was a different story

Answer (score 0):

```js
const parsed_data = [ {"begin": "2018-01-01", "end": "2018-01-07", "id":"a"}, {"begin":"2018-01-08", "end":"2018-01-15", "id":"b"}, {"begin":"2018-03-01", "end":"2018-03-07", "id":"y"}]

let client_date = new Date(2018, 1, 2);

let data = parsed_data.filter(value => {

    const end_date_parts  = value['end'].split('-');

    const end_date = new Date(end_date_parts[0], end_date_parts[1]-1, end_date_parts[2]);

    // compare now client_date

    if (client_date <= end_date){
        return value;
    }
});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Of course is empty. because as you say "sometimes a week might not exist. so in that case, get the next closest group." there is no next closest group in parsed_data. the last end date is 2018-03-07 and input is 2018-12-2.

Comment: That seems to return all dates that are less than client_date. So in my real JSON, I have 40 weeks and I get 31 array elements now -- all of which have end date less than end date

Comment: just replace filter with some. parsed_data.filter to parsed_data.some. "some" break as soon as possible when there is a true condition.